# TCP Client sometimes merges data-packets

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, mono, unity-container

In a Unity-application I'm receiving like 160 JSON-Objects via TCP per second. My reading code below seems to struggle at such rates and a few times doesn't `processData` them as single messages. When trying to create a [JSONObject](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=JSONObject)` instead I get something like this

> improper JSON
>   formatting:right","data":{"type":"flex","gesture":"open","data":[0.11425240454677936,0.11582253631723596,0.0947054436987323,0]}}{"type":"right","data":{"type":"sensor","data":[0.98638916015625,-0.0802001953125,0.08880615234375,-0.11248779296875,null]}}{"type":"right","data":{"type":"flex","gesture":"open","data":[0.11192072282133489,0.11739301138594425,0.09271687795177729,0]}}{"type":"right","data":{"type":"sensor","data":[0.98638916015625,-0.0802001953125,0.08880615234375,-0.11248779296875,null]}}{"type":"right",

This is my data processing function:

```
bool ProcessData()
{
    string temp = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(readBuffer);
    //Debug.Log(string.Format("Client recv: '{0}'", temp));

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(temp);
}
```

Here's my TCP-code:

```
void connectToHub () {
    readBuffer = new byte[512];
    EndPoint endpoint;
    if (this.useUnixSocket == true) {
        endpoint = new UnixEndPoint(SOCKET_LOCATION);
    } else {
        endpoint = new IPEndPoint(this.ipAdress, this.port);
    }

    client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try {
        IAsyncResult result = client.BeginConnect(endpoint, 
                                    new AsyncCallback(this.EndConnect), 
                                    null);
        bool connectSuccess = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        if (!connectSuccess){
            client.Close();
            Debug.LogError(string.Format("Client unable to connect. Failed"));
        }

    }
    catch(SystemException e) {
        Debug.LogError(string.Format("Client exception on beginconnect: {0}", e.Message));
    }

}

void EndConnect(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    client.EndConnect(iar);
    client.NoDelay = true;
    ReceiveData();
}


void ReceiveData()
{
    client.BeginReceive(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, EndReceiveData, client);
}

void EndReceiveData(System.IAsyncResult iar)
{
    int numBytesReceived = client.EndReceive(iar);
    if (numBytesReceived > 0){
        this.ProcessData();

    }           
    // Continue receiving data
    ReceiveData();
}
```

Comment: Best way to think about it: TCP *always* merges data-packets.  It implements a *stream*.  If you want to super-impose your own protocol on to top of TCP then that's not difficult.  HTTP did.  It sends the packet size first, the receiver just count down.

Comment: That makes sense. Would it be preferable to use `TCPClient` instead of `Socket`?

Comment: No, it does not change the protocol.

Comment: Would I execute two `BeginReceive` in a row in `ReceiveData()`? The first one to determine the requests size and the 2nd one for the actual request or will this lead to other problems? I'm not sure how to structure the code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that at times you start processing the data before it has all arrived. You are calling `EndReceiveData` when you receive some data over TCP. If all the data fitted into the packet that has just arrived, you have no problem. If, however, the data is bigger than the packet, then you really should be reading all of the packets for that json object, before you start to parse it.

Comment: Why does it work then if I limit the rate to like 40 packets per second (the packets are the same size) ?